# Non repeating and minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement where in i need to find the lowest and non repeating value in a sql column. Let me describe it

```
Sno. User amount
1.   1001 $0.02
2.   1002 $0.03
3.   1003 $0.04
5.   1004 $0.02
6.   1005 $0.05
```

In this scenario, in the amount column although $0.02 is the minimum, but we can see that it is also preset twice(repeating) in the column, so the next minimum and non repeating value is $0.03 and which is what I want.
I tried using Distinct but it gives all the values in the amount column I just need the one. I don't care about the higher values $0.04 and $0.05 here.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MIN()` with `GROUP BY.. HAVING`:

```
SELECT MIN(amount)
FROM (SELECT amount
      FROM table
      GROUP BY amount
      HAVING COUNT(1) = 1) a
```

Comment: it will give all the rows that have a count =1, i just need 1 row i.e. $0.03 in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` while taking the `MIN`:

```
Select   Min(Amount)
From
(
    Select   Amount
    From     YourTable
    Group By Amount
    Having   Count(*) = 1
) As A
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT amount
FROM t
GROUP BY amount
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY amount ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or, if you really wanted to be fancy with no aggregation:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.sno = t.sno and t2.amount = t.amount)
order by t.amount
limit 1;
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can get all the other values from the column as well.